# Stop SQL Server jobs from adding event log for success

Tags: sql-server, event-log

My eventlog is cluttered with `Package "<name>" finished successfully` messages; is there any way to stop these from being added to the log?

The packages in question run very frequently and are making the eventlog harder to use

This is running from SQL Server 2008 R2 (Standard)

The job properties are set with **Write to the Windows Application event log - When the job fails** (and sends an email to an operator and in the corresponding maintenance plan, the settings for "Reporting and Logging" are all set with nothing checked.

And the SQL Server Agent properties are set only with the fail-safe operator; by email

For the life of me, I cannot see anywhere in SQL where I can suppress the "success" messages and would appreciate help.

Comment: I perosnally think you should make better use of filters, possibly write a custom query on the log, but to reduce the basic logging entirely seems dangerous and undesireable.

Comment: I agree with @Tristan. Why do you want to suppress the built in auditing of your job? The whole point of a log is to track activity. Either use filters or create your own error logging and just reference that. At some point somebody will ask what time(s) this job ran successfully last September and with the logs you will be able to answer that.

Comment: That is a very confrontational way to answer this question Sean and not at all constructive!  Surely you are not implying the OP is doing something wrong?  I suggest you edit your answer to be less combative and judgemental.  Ironically however the actual substance of your suggestion is correct - filtering is clearly the way to go here.  If you were to present that information in a positive way you would get my up vote.

Comment: The events in question are trivial processes that really do not need to be logged; we can confirm their success through a number of other means; so these logs are simply bloating the event logs and making other, more important processes hard to check (even when filtering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just encountered a very similar scenario.

I have a couple of packages that are scheduled frequently.  Monitoring of these non-critical packages can be managed within SQL Server Management Studio itself, I have no need to log events to the Windows Application logs.

In fact the logs are now "bloating" insofar as they are filling at a far greater pace than I am happy with.

It is possible to switch package logging on or off within the SSIS package itself.

From within BIDS (Business Intelligence Design Studio), right click anywhere within the control flow and  select "Logging..." from the menu that appears.

From what I have read of this, to set your own custom logging options you have to tick the option on in the "Providers and Logs" screen and then add the "SSIS log provider for Windows Event Log" provider.

Once you have done that, you can tick options on and off within the "Details" tab.  The options are all unchecked by default.

In the alternative, you could set up logging to the "SSIS log provider for SQL Server" and select the items that you *do* want to monitor. This then logs activity to a table called dbo.sysssislog in whichever database you configure within the provider.

You can get details on SSIS package logging here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181205(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: This is clearly THE answer, at least to the spirit of the OP's original question.  Filters are in some ways more logical, but equally I genuinely think there are times when it is reasonable to cull the event log.  This IS one of those time.  In my opinion MS needs to offer a better MMC snapin with more features for viewing event logs.  Another approach would probably be through the 'Powershell' console and various pipes.